# Is this AND+CMP between the same two operands just checking for one of them being zero?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to reading assembly, but I think I mostly understand how assembly instructions work. Here's a function that got me puzzled:

```
mov  ecx, dword [ecx + 0x28]
mov  eax, dword [esp + 0x04]
and  ecx, eax
xor  edx, edx
cmp  ecx, eax
sete dl
mov  eax, edx
ret  4
```

I believe this translates roughly to the following pseudocode:

```
let ecx = <read memory at ecx+0x28>
let eax = <read from stack at 0x04, probably function argument>
ecx = ecx + eax;
if (ecx == eax) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

So the only way for `ecx` to equal `eax` after adding is if `ecx == 0`, and loading `eax` and adding look completely unnecessary. What am I missing here? What could be the purpose of those additional operations?

Comment: @InstructionPointer : really generic titles are generally not useful.  I'm going to roll back because I can't think of a better specific title without putting the answer in the question (that it's AND not ADD)

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand, there's plenty a person can learn from this QA but the linking verbs are confusing. Ironic that "generic is generally..." something. Anyway, I'm always open to your feedback Peter, thanks for the courtesy.

Comment: @InstructionPointer: oh yes, the original title has broken grammar.  That can be fixed.

Comment: @InstructionPointer: finally came up with a better title that includes the specific question.  Repeating the instructions in the title makes the mistake much more obvious, but the main point of SO is searchability for future readers so that always takes priority.  Most brain farts / misreading errors aren't searchable unless by copy/paste of the relevant instructions, and this still achieves that

Comment: Very nice! Maybe I was just too wiped out from the work week while still trying to push myself here on SO to see it. I just try to contribute when I see a need. This has been a good learning experience for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's `and` not `add`.

`x & mask == mask` is the standard idiom for checking that *all* the bits in `mask` are set in `x`.

`and ecx, eax` alone (or `test ecx, eax`) would clear ZF if at least one bit is set, so you can't distinguish between that and all bits.

---

Also, since the asm is branchless using xor/cmp/setcc, a closer transliteration to C would be `return (x & mask) == mask;` not an `if/else`.  The xor-zero might just be to avoid a false dependency, but if it's from clang then it's because the return value is `int`, not `bool`.